# How to create csr, key, crt and import crt, rootca, subca into jks?

Tags: java, bash, openssl, keytool, jks

To overcome the doubt of expertise I just explain the process, by which we are able to generate **csr** and **key**?

```
# generate a new private key and certificate signing request
openssl req -out chorke.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes \
-keyout chorke.key
```

Please confirm us who is responsible for create **crt** either **client** or **server**? Here **we are acting as client** and if we have to create **crt** from **csr** & **key** then we are able to create **chorke.crt** as following:

```
# generate certificate using csr & key
openssl x509 -req -in chorke.csr -signkey chorke.key \
-out chorke.crt
```

If the **sever authority** responsible for create **chorke.crt** then guide us the procedure? Else we could send **chorke.crt** to sever authority to add it to their server. After that the sever authority send us their **rootca**, **subca**(intermediate ca) and **chorke.crt**. Then we have to import them to a fresh **client.jks** as following:

```
keytool -storepass storepasswd -importcert -keystore client.jks \
-trustcacerts -alias rootca -file rootca.cer

keytool -storepass storepasswd -importcert -keystore client.jks \
-trustcacerts -alias subca -file subca.cer

keytool -storepass storepasswd -importcert -keystore client.jks \
-alias chorke -file chorke.crt
```

After that we are ablie to run **java program** as following and **causes bad certificate error**

```
java \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./client.jks \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=storepasswd \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=./client.jks \
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=storepasswd \
-cp ./lib/*:./bin ChorkeServerTest
```

What's the wrong goes in this procedure as above? In this situation we expect suggestion from expertise, to point out the errata and guide us the step from generation of **csr** to import into **jks** and run **java program** successfully .

Comment: chorke.crt is a selfsigned certificate. From what you wrote I guess that the chorke.crt should be created by subca instead. So you need to send chorke.csr to subca and they should return chorke.crt

Comment: is chorke.crt supposed to be a client certificate?

Comment: **chorke.crt** created by **subca** authority based on our **chorke.csr**. and it's a client certificate.

Comment: Can you try to connect to the server using some other client? For example `openssl s_client`

Comment: How will I pass certificate in `openssl s_client`? Example please?  For **client.jks** do I need to import **chorke.key** or some things else?

Comment: From [openssl docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/openssl-s_client.html):`openssl s_client -cert chorke.crt -key chorke.key -CAfile rootca.cer -connect host:port`

Comment: openssl pkcs12 -export -in STAR_ravi_com.crt -inkey STAR_ravi_com.key -out STAR_ravi_com.p12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore STAR_ravi_com.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12   -destkeystore STAR_ravi_com.jks -deststoretype JKS
Enter destination keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
Enter source keystore password:
Entry for alias 1 successfully imported.
Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled

Answer (score 1):

Please find in the below series of **keytool** and **openssl** commands used to create **.jks** file from **.p12** certificate, extract/list the **.jks** key store configuration as part of **.txt** file, change the default alias to the expected alias, use **openssl** command to convert the **.p12** certificate to **.cer**, configure/import the **root-ca** and **intermediate-ca** certificates as part of **.jks** key store file.

**keytool** command to create **my_keystore.jks** file with entry type as **PrivateKeyEntry**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "D:\Certificates\DLOMTE.p12" -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore "my_keystore.jks" -deststoretype jks
```

**keytool** command to list/extract the **my_keystore.jks** configuration as **my_keystore.txt** file

```
keytool -list -v -keystore my_keystore.jks > my_keystore.txt
```

**keytool** command to change the default alias name in **my_keystore.jks** file

```
keytool -changealias -alias "<ALIAS NAME AS IN THE KEYSTORE>" -destalias "at oces - prod" -keystore my_keystore.jks
```

**openssl** command to convert **.p12** certificate to **.cer**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in "D:\Certificates\DLOMTE.p12" -clcerts -nokeys -out "D:\Certificates\DLOMTE.cer"
```

**keytool** command to import the **rootca** certificate as part of **my_keystore.jks** file with required alias

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias "at oces - prod - rootca" -file "D:\Certificates\OCESPrimaryCA-RootCA.cer" -keystore my_keystore.jks
```

**keytool** command to import the **intermediateca** certificate as part of **my_keystore.jks** file with required alias

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias "at oces - prod - intermediateca" -file "D:\Certificates\OCESPrimaryCA-IntermediateCA.cer" -keystore my_keystore.jks
```